# Having trouble getting Merge sort to be O(n log n)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort

In full disclosure, I'm a student and having trouble with merge sort.  The purpose is obviously to have a O(n log n), but it's more n^2.  I think the problem lies within the tempList, as you'll see in the code, but in the program description it says to use static int tempList[LIST_SIZE] to avoid degradation.

Here's what I have and the runtime using start is around 16000, which is obviously way to long for the merge sort.

```
    void mergeSort(int randomNum[], int lowIdx, int highIdx)
    {
        int midIdx;

        if (lowIdx < highIdx)
        {
            midIdx = (highIdx + lowIdx) / 2;
            mergeSort(randomNum, lowIdx, midIdx);
            mergeSort(randomNum, midIdx + 1, highIdx);
            merge(randomNum, lowIdx, midIdx, highIdx);
        }
    }
```

Here is the second portion of the sort

```
    void merge(int randomNum[], int lowIdx, int midIdx, int highIdx)
    {
        static int tempList[MAX_SORT];

        for (int count = 0; count <= highIdx; count++)
            tempList[count] = randomNum[count];

        int leftIdx = lowIdx,
        rightIdx = midIdx + 1,
        tempPos = lowIdx;

        while (leftIdx <= midIdx && (rightIdx <= highIdx))
        {
            if (tempList[leftIdx] <= tempList[rightIdx])
            {
                randomNum[tempPos] = tempList[leftIdx];
                leftIdx++;
            }
            else
            {
                randomNum[tempPos] = tempList[rightIdx];
                rightIdx++;
            }
        tempPos++;
        }

        while (leftIdx <= midIdx)
        {
            randomNum[tempPos] = tempList[leftIdx];
            tempPos++;
            leftIdx++;
        }

        while (rightIdx <= highIdx)
        {
            randomNum[tempPos] = tempList[rightIdx];
            tempPos++;
            rightIdx++;
        }
    }
```

The details of the program are that we have an array with 100000 random numbers and sort it using various sorting algorithms.  The other sorts are working as expected, but this one seems to be off by a lot in comparison to what the big-O is supposed to be.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is all of your problem, but this is one issue:

You are copying `randomNum` to `tempList` from `0` to `highIdx`, but you only ever access `tempList` from `lowIdx` to `highIdx`.

That means that all the items you copied from `0` to `lowIdx` are wasted copies.

Solution: Only copy what you need.

```
for (int count = lowIdx; count <= highIdx; count++)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew I had the code correct, except for something involving the tempList, but wasn't sure what was wrong.  That completely fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a bottom up merge sort. Example template code. a[] is the array to be sorted, b[] is a temp array with the same size as a[]. The sorted data may end up in either a[] or b[]. This can be modified to always end up with the data in a[] by doing a pass count check at the start and optionally skipping the swap in place if there will be an even number of passes.

```
template <typename T>
T * BottomUpMergeSort(T a[], T b[], size_t n)
{
    for(size_t s = 1; s < n; s += 2)        // swap in place for 1st pass
        if(a[s] < a[s-1])
            std::swap(a[s], a[s-1]);
    for(size_t s = 2; s < n; s <<= 1){      // s = run size
        size_t ee = 0;                      // init end index
        while(ee < n){                      // merge pairs of runs
            size_t ll = ee;                 // ll = start of left  run
            size_t rr = ll+s;               // rr = start of right run
            if(rr >= n){                    // if only left run
                rr = n;
                BottomUpCopy(a, b, ll, rr); //   copy left run
                break;                      //   end of pass
            }
            ee = rr+s;                      // ee = end of right run
            if(ee > n)
                ee = n;
            BottomUpMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                    // swap a and b
    }
    return a;                               // return sorted array
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpCopy(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr)
{
    while(ll < rr){                         // copy left run
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        ll++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index

    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee){                  //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr){                  //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```